# Error: Injector already created, can not register a module! Angular 1.2 jasmine 1.3.0

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

i'm writing a small application in angular and jasmine 1.3 for my test.

First test is working fine, but i have a situation with the second one.

here is a snippet of code with witch i'm struggling:

```
describe('helperFactoryTest', function() {

    var helperFactory = null,
        items = [
            {id : 1, item : 'Apples', qty : 2, type : 2, done : 1 },
            {id : 2, item : 'Bread', qty : 1, type : 1,  done : 1 },
            {id : 3, item : 'Bananas', qty : 5, type : 2,  done : 0 },
            {id : 4, item : 'Pears', qty : 8, type : 2,  done : 0 }
        ],

        thisItems = [];

    beforeEach(function() {

        module('myApp');

        inject(function(_helperFactory_) {

            helperFactory = _helperFactory_;

        });
    });


    it('should filter array and return records that are completed (done)',
        function() {

            thisItems = helperFactory.filterFieldArrayByDone(items, 'id', 1);

            expect(thisItems.length).toEqual(2);

        }
    );


describe('ShoppingLIstController helper methods test', function() {

    var $scope,
        helperFactory,
        ShoppingListController;


    beforeEach(function() {

        module('myApp');

        inject(function($rootScope, _helperFactory_, $controller) {

           $scope = $rootScope.$new();

           helperFactory = _helperFactory_;

           ShoppingListController = $controller('ShoppingListController', {

               $scope : $scope,
               helperFactory : helperFactory

           });

        });

    });


    it('should return 0 for 2 characters', function() {

        $scope.item = '12';

        expect($scope.howManyMoreCharactersNeeded()).toEqual(0);

    });


});



});
```

Here is the function that i'm calling in my test:

```
$scope.howManyMoreCharactersNeeded = function() {

                var characters = (MIN_LENGTH - $scope.item.length);

                return (characters > 0) ? characters : 0;

            };
```

MIN_LENGTH is equal to 2;

$scope.item.length is the length of characters in textfield;

Can you please tell me what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

From  my understanding and after coming across exactly similar problem, what i have understood is that , **The "modules" that need to be mocked into tests are supposed to be placed at the top, before any other "inject()", that is used to handle special dependencies.**

So, considering your case , you have a **nested suite (describe('ShoppingLIstController helper methods test') )**, where, you are trying to **mock the  module** again.

I presume, that you might have **forgot to close the first suite ( ie, 'helperFactoryTest' )** , which evidently made your next suite as the nested one. So, clearly analysing your suite's opening and closing brackets and **terminating** your 1st suite solve the error you have come across.

If that is not the case, and if you are into the **nested suite**, then,
note  the comments from the below code , which points out the cause of the problem.

```
 describe('helperFactoryTest', function() {                 // Parent suite
   var helperFactory = null,
       items = [
            {id : 1, item : 'Apples', qty : 2, type : 2, done : 1 },
                   .
                   .
            {id : 4, item : 'Pears', qty : 8, type : 2,  done : 0 }
    ],
    thisItems = [];
    beforeEach(function() {
        module('myApp');                      //  First Module Mock

        inject(function(_helperFactory_) {    // First inject()
            helperFactory = _helperFactory_;
        });
    });
    it('should filter array and return records that are completed (done)',
        function() {
            //Some test       
        }
    );
    describe('ShoppingLIstController helper methods test', function() {  // Nested Suite
    var $scope,
        helperFactory,
        ShoppingListController;
    beforeEach(function() {

                                  /*   Trying to mock the Module again  */
                                  /*    after parent suite's inject() 
            module('myApp');      /*    This is what is triggering error  */
                                  /* REMOVE THIS MODULE MOCK FROM THIS SUITE */ 

        inject(function($rootScope, _helperFactory_, $controller) {

           $scope = $rootScope.$new();
           helperFactory = _helperFactory_;
           ShoppingListController = $controller('ShoppingListController', {
               $scope : $scope,
               helperFactory : helperFactory
           });
        });
    });
    it('should return 0 for 2 characters', function() {
        //Some Test
    });
  });
});
```

Hope this helps

Cheers.